Group Policy not applied: access denied
I created a new AD security group, added all users i need. Within our GPO "FolderRedirection" in the security filter tab, I removed  Authenticated Users and added the new AD security group into the security filter with read and apply permission. I also added  Authenticated Users with read permission.
Goal is: We want certain users to have their documents folder redirected to their respective documents folder in their shared home drive instead of the local documents folder. Some users though, mostly remote etc., don't want or need this redirection, therefore the new security group instead of authenticated users.
When running gpupdate /force and after gpresult /r it says that the GPO "FolderRedirection" cannot be applied "Access denied" and the new AD security group does not appear under "The user is part of the following security groups" even though I am.
When I add Authenticated Users with "apply gpo" permission, it works as expected.
We use two domain controllers, but I've checked, they replicate almost instantly.


the new AD-Group doesnt show up under "The user is part of the following security groups" eventhough I am

You need to log off and log on to obtain the new group membership.

Actually there is no need to logoff, runinng this in command line should do the trick:
klist purge

Sorry, my fault, you actually NEED to logoff because "Folder Redirection" processing is effective only during the logon.
klist purge will give you a new domain group membership, but it is not enough in this particular case.

Is there a reason you don't want to use the 'advanced - specify locations for various user groups' setting for each folder? That way you could probably leave the Security tab in the original state and adjust the paths for specific user groups inside the policy.
Also, you can check the "Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational" event log on the client to look for clues.
